# Is content of the document depends on the SQLite FTS5 when ranking?

Tags: sqlite, ranking, fts5

Following are two example sentences.

(1) Within a year **Microsoft** **licensed** MS-DOS to over 70 other companies. It was designed to be an OS that could run on any 8086-family computer.

(2) Within a year **Microsoft** **license** MS-DOS to over 70 other companies. It was designed to be an OS that could run on any 8086-family computer. Each computer would have its own distinct hardware and its own version of MS-DOS.

When searching **Microsoft** as the input search text, (1) is getting a higher rank than the (2) because (1) has a lower content.

When searching **license** as the input search text, best match is in (2). Since (1) has a smaller content than the (2), will output a higher rank for (1).

Is there any way to get the ranking of the exact match without looking at the content? Any solutions?

Comment: Are you using BM25?

Comment: Yes I'm using BM25(). Default ranking method is BM25() right? Is there any other way to get the ranking without referring to the content?

Comment: What do you mean with "default"? Show the actual query you're using.

Comment: This is the Query :

SELECT column1, rank FROM FullTextSearchTable WHERE FullTextSearchTable MATCH 'serchText*' ORDER BY rank

Comment: > All FTS5 tables feature a special hidden column named "rank". If the current query is not a full-text query (i.e. if it does not include a MATCH operator), the value of the "rank" column is always NULL. Otherwise, in a full-text query, column rank contains by default the same value as would be returned by executing the bm25() auxiliary function with no trailing arguments.

https://sqlite.org/fts5.html#sorting_by_auxiliary_function_results